# Have causative verb get causative verb

Tags: grammaticality, causative-have, causative-get

I am in confusion  of using causative verb 'have'
If i write 
"I wanted to have you sit on the chair".
" i wanted to get you to sit on the chair".
"Why did you get him to come with you?"
Are those grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: To me, the _have_ causitive is not idiomatic with a full verb (eg _sit_), though it is with a bare participle (eg _Have a house built_). The construction you use (_have someone sit_) sounds American to me.

Answer (score 1):

> "I wanted to have you sit on the chair"
>
> and
>
> "I wanted to get you to sit on the chair"

are for all intents and purposes identical in meaning, and both are grammatically correct. Both are in common use, although they're slightly less formal than using other, more specific verbs (like "I wanted you to sit").